# Interpreting a passage from the manual

Tags: regex, bioinformatics, fasta

I'm trying to get some bioinformatics software to run (TE Displayer) but it's simply not working. I think the problem might be in how the software is recognizing the FASTA headers. From the documentation this is said.

> The sequence identifiers in the header lines take a pattern of "\w(1,10)\d(2,9)" meaning "word characters (1-10) followed by numbers (2-9)", so try to avoid a non-identifier phrase (e.g. "Build04") in the header line. For example the header line ">OrganismX Accession AC000282, build0.4" is fine, but not ">OrganismX Contig WX000282, Build04" . Accordingly, ">Oryza sativa Chromosome11" will also be fine because "Chromosome11" will be recognized as the identifier.

Can someone explain the exact usage of "\w(1,10)\d(2,9)" I understand it as any word up to 12 characters long in total but it must end in two digits. So I don't understand how Build0.4 is fine while Build04 is not fine.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence identifiers alone should match the pattern, so in `">OrganismX Accession AC000282, build0.4"`, its the `AC000282` that must be matched by the regex , not `Build0.4`.

`\w(1,10)\d(2,9)` means match from one to ten word characters, i.e. any of `a-z A-Z 0-9 _`, followed by from two to nine digits.

Because `Build04` would be matched by that pattern and it is not the sequence identifier, it is recommended to be avoided. 
`build0.4` will not match that pattern because it contains a `.`, so it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what MikeM said-
You are trying to get your script to identify the `AC000282`. 
The above regex would identify that sequence of characters. 
The sequence identifier `\w(1,10)\d(2,9)` says "Find 1 to 10 word characters followed by 2 to 9 digit characters.
The regex would then identify `Build04` as there are 5 word characters (BUILD) followed by 2 digit characters(04), but it would not identify `Build0.4` as the `.` within `Build0.4` would tell the regex that it is not to be used.